# Java BounceBall Movimento da Bolha - Erro

Tags: java, swing

Estou fazendo um game de BounceBall, usando iteração com o ponteiro do mouse. 
Mas me deparei com um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver.

A ideia geral é que, as bolhas se movimentem pela tela, e ao encontrarem o ponteiro do mouse, mudem de direção. 
Mas meu método está meio bugado, para algumas bolhas funciona, mas para grande parte delas  não. Elas ficam "travadas" no canto superior esquerdo da tela.

Alguém consegue me dar uma luz do que está errado??

Meu problema está no método "Move".

Segue meu fonte:

```
public class SimpleBalls {

    private Point mousePoint;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SimpleBalls();
    }

    public SimpleBalls() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager
                            .getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Spot");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                Balls balls = new Balls();
                frame.add(balls);
                frame.setSize(400, 400);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                new Thread(new BounceEngine(balls)).start();

            }
        });
    }

    public static int random(int maxRange) {
        return (int) Math.round((Math.random() * maxRange));
    }

    public class Balls extends JPanel {

        private List<Ball> ballsUp;

        public Balls() {
            ballsUp = new ArrayList<Ball>(25);

            MouseAdapter handler = new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    mousePoint = e.getPoint();
                    // System.out.println(mousePoint);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    mousePoint = null;
                }

            };

            addMouseListener(handler);
            addMouseMotionListener(handler);

            for (int index = 0; index < 1 + random(2); index++) {
                ballsUp.add(new Ball(new Color(random(255), random(255),
                        random(255))));
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            for (Ball ball : ballsUp) {
                ball.paint(g2d);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public List<Ball> getBalls() {
            return ballsUp;
        }
    }

    public class BounceEngine implements Runnable {

        private Balls parent;

        public BounceEngine(Balls parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            int width = getParent().getWidth();
            int height = getParent().getHeight();

            for (Ball ball : getParent().getBalls()) {
                int x = random(width);
                int y = random(height);

                Dimension size = ball.getSize();

                if (x + size.width > width) {
                    x = width - size.width;
                }
                if (y + size.height > height) {
                    y = height - size.height;
                }

                ball.setLocation(new Point(x, y));

            }

            while (getParent().isVisible()) {

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getParent().repaint();
                    }
                });

                for (Ball ball : getParent().getBalls()) {
                    move(ball, mousePoint);
                }

                // for (Ball ball : getParent().getBalls()) {
                // move(ball, mousePoint);
                // }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }

        public Balls getParent() {
            return parent;
        }

        public void move(Ball ball, Point mouse) {

            try {
                Point p = ball.getLocation();
                Point speed = ball.getSpeed();
                Dimension size = ball.getSize();

                int dimeter = ball.dimeter;

                int vx = speed.x;
                int vy = speed.y;

                int x = p.x;
                int y = p.y;

                // ----------------------
                if (mouse != null) {

                    int xDistance = Math.abs(x + (size.width / 2) - mouse.x);
                    int yDistance = Math.abs(y + (size.height / 2) - mouse.y);

                    if (xDistance < yDistance) {
                        if (x + (size.width / 2) < mouse.x) {
                            if (vx > 0) {
                                vx *= -1;
                                System.out
                                        .println("1 - MOUSE - x: " + x
                                                + " Dimeter: " + size.width
                                                + " Dimeter/2: "
                                                + (size.width / 2)
                                                + " Mouse X: " + mouse.x
                                                + " VX: " + vx);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (vx > 0) {
                                vx *= -1;
                                System.out
                                        .println("2 - MOUSE - x: " + x
                                                + " Dimeter: " + size.width
                                                + " Dimeter/2: "
                                                + (size.width / 2)
                                                + " Mouse X: " + mouse.x
                                                + " VX: " + vx);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (y + (size.height / 2) < mouse.y) {
                            if (vy > 0) {
                                vy *= -1;
                                System.out
                                        .println("3 - MOUSE - y: " + y
                                                + " Dimeter: " + size.height
                                                + " Dimeter/2: "
                                                + (size.height / 2)
                                                + " Mouse Y: " + mouse.y
                                                + " VY: " + vy);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (vy > 0) {
                                vy *= -1;
                                System.out
                                        .println("4 - MOUSE - y: " + y
                                                + " Dimeter: " + size.height
                                                + " Dimeter/2: "
                                                + (size.height / 2)
                                                + " Mouse Y: " + mouse.y
                                                + " VY: " + vy);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

                // ----------------------

                if (x + vx < 0 || x + size.width + vx > getParent().getWidth()) {
                    vx *= -1;
                    System.out.println("1 - N ");
                }
                if (y + vy < 0
                        || y + size.height + vy > getParent().getHeight()) {
                    vy *= -1;
                    System.out.println("2 - N ");
                }
                x += vx;
                y += vy;

                ball.setSpeed(new Point(vx, vy));
                ball.setLocation(new Point(x, y));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public class Ball {

        private Color color;
        private Point location;
        private Dimension size;
        private Point speed;
        private int dimeter;

        public Ball(Color color) {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            dimeter = 10 + rnd.nextInt(50);

            setColor(color);

            speed = new Point(10 - random(20), 10 - random(20));
            size = new Dimension(dimeter, dimeter);

        }

        public Dimension getSize() {
            return size;
        }

        public void setColor(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public void setLocation(Point location) {
            this.location = location;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public Point getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        public Point getSpeed() {
            return speed;
        }

        public void setSpeed(Point speed) {
            this.speed = speed;
        }

        protected void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {

            Point p = getLocation();
            if (p != null) {
                g2d.setColor(getColor());
                Dimension size = getSize();
                g2d.fillOval(p.x, p.y, size.width, size.height);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alguém??? Alguma dica?

Comment: Você está considerando o diametro ao avaliar se ela tocou nos cantos da janela?

Comment: Fernando, apesar de seu código não estar bem organizado, isso é, não adotou nenhum padrão (MVC, MVP, etc..), dei uma pequena simplicada em algumas partes que estavam muito complexas sem necessidade, o código está quase funcionando. Como estou sem tempo agora, coloquei o código que deixei nesse gist: https://gist.github.com/wakim/424973a8e2d2dca282b0

Comment: @Caputo Sim, em relação as laterais, ele está batendo e mudando de direção corretamente, mas não consegui entender o motivo das bolhas ficarem bugadas quando o mouse está na tela..

Comment: @Wakim realmente, fui desenvolvendo, pesquisando e não deixei muito organizado. Vou dar uma olhada no que você fez ali. Obrigado.

Comment: @Wakim Cara, show de bola... Mudei 2 coisas aqui, e está funcionando perfeitamente.. Não creio que me bati tanto com isto. Faz todo sentido o que você fez. Só arrumei a colisão com o mouse levando em consideração o diâmetro. De resto 100%. Posta aí que encerro a dúvida. Show... Muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Ok, quando eu chegar em casa eu posto.

Comment: @Wakim Valeu mesmo cara... Obrigado. Me ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código tinha algumas lógicas que não entendi muito bem, em relação a detecção da colisão com o mouse. Fiz a minha própria, onde apenas verifico se a distância entre a posição do `mouse` menos a posição do centro da bola, considerando a velocidade (isso precisa ser revisto talvez) é menor que o raio.

Acho que vale a pena rever essa lógica, porque a deteção é preditora, isso é, está detectando antes de desenhar o frame (pode causar problemas para bolas com velocidade alta).

```
if (mouse != null) {
    // Nesse metodo esta sendo desenhado a bola no proximo frame, logo eu considero o vx e vy na colisao 
    int xDistance = Math.abs((x + vx) - mouse.x);
    int yDistance = Math.abs((y + vy) - mouse.y);

    System.out.printf("b(%d, %d) m(%d, %d) dx(%d, %d)\n", x, y, mouse.x, mouse.y, (x + vx) - mouse.x, (y + vy) - mouse.y);

    if (xDistance <= raioX && yDistance <= raioY) {
        // Essa logica de alteracao pode variar se quiser
        if(xDistance < yDistance) {
            vx *= -1;
        } else {
            vy *= -1;
        }

        System.out.println("Bateu!");
    }
}
```

Seu código com relação a colisão com borda estava quase certo, só faltou considerar o raio e não o diâmetro da bola e também a velocidade. Não há colisão se a bola esta em uma borda mas está com velocidade em com sentido ao centro.

Fiz uma simplicação:

```
// Lado esquerdo
if (x + vx - (size.width/2)) < 0 && vx < 0) {
    vx *= -1;
}

// Lado direito
if((x + (size.width/2)) + vx > getParent().getWidth() && vx > 0) {
    vx *= -1;
}

// Baixo
if (y + vy - (size.width/2)) < 0 && vy < 0) {
    vy *= -1;
}

// Cima
if((y + (size.height/2)) + vy > getParent().getHeight() && vy > 0) {
    vy *= -1;
}
```

É claro que ainda assim pode reduzir o número de calculo, reutilizando variáveis e tudo mais. Mas ai são otimizações posteriores.

Comment: Wakim, obrigado pela ajuda. Sou novato em relação a Swing no java. Valeu mesmo.